# Angular HttpClient - how to convert from Http: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))._body)?

Tags: json, angular, angular-httpclient

Using the Http module, this construction is used:

Http service:

```
let tokenUrl1 = this.apiUrl + 'login';
let headers1 = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
return this.http.post(tokenUrl1, JSON.stringify(model), {headers: headers1});
```

Call of the service:

```
this.loginService.sendCredential(this.model).subscribe(
  data => {
    // Next statement ... how to convert this for use in an HttpClint environment??
    localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))._body);
```

The nice HttpClient module parses the http content body with JSON returning an object. Nice!

How can the marked statement, "**JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))._body)**" be rewritten to fit nicely in the HttpClient environment?

Comment: `data._body`? Why are you stringifying and parsing?

Comment: This statement was in a course on connecting Spring Boot and Angular with JWT security. Works great for a year. But I cannot use it in the HttpClient environment. When I see on the internet, this is a special (deep copy?) construction. That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can manipulate the return type to string - that is sufficient for e.g. tokens:

```
let tokenUrl2 = this.apiUrl + 'users';
let getHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Bearer '+token});
return this.httpClient.get(tokenUrl2, { observe: 'body', responseType: 'text', headers: getHeaders})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use response as JSON object directly to get value like this.

```
this.loginService.sendCredential(this.model).subscribe(
  data => {
    let res = data.json();
    let tokenValue = res['token']; // based on your json response...
    localStorage.setItem("token", tokenValue);
}
```

And If you are using api-call with type then...(From Angular Doc)

```
showConfig() {
  this.configService.getConfig()
    .subscribe((data: Response) => {
    // like data.xyz properties of 'Reponse' class
    // here you can get values from Your 'Reponse' class directly instead of parsing as above.
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Ask me if any query.

Comment: The HttpClient post returns an object directly. In similar cases I didn't have to perform data.json(). So, I guess json() is not wanted/needed in HttpClient this time?

Comment: If you are using type with api-call. then you can refer https://angular.io/guide/http#getting-json-data official doc.

Comment: Thanx, Please elaborate a bit in your answer on what you mean with "using type with api-call. I normally expect typed api calls with a syntax like "httpClient.get<UserResponse>( ...) ".

Answer (score 0):

You can add observe in your header.

```
let tokenUrl1 = this.apiUrl + 'login';
let headers1 = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
return this.http.post(tokenUrl1, JSON.stringify(model), {
   headers: headers1,
   observe: 'response'
});
```

And

```
this.loginService.sendCredential(this.model).subscribe(
  data => {
    console.log(data.body);
```